Is there a way to log test results from CANoe directly to csv via CAPL?
I'm working on the test case implementation in CANoe using CAPL.
Because I have to upload the test report in another system I need the csv file. Right now I can only see the test results either in HTLM/XML or via the Test Case Reviewer proved by CANoe. HTML/XML  to csv conversion is not an option at the moment
So is there way to export the results of the test cases directly in csv, using CAPL? I saw this tread CAPL writing to Text file(CAPL writing to Text file), but not sure if this will work.
All insight and advices will be of great help!
Best Regards!
Nothing was tried yet. Looking for advice.

As you have already found out, you can write to a file using CAPL. Not sure what you are asking though...

I want the test results (pass/fail) which is provided in a HTML to be directly exported in csv.

What about simply converting the XML to CSV?
